# SQL SERVER SSIS and ADO.NET driver for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Do I need to install the [MySQL ADO.net](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) driver to use a mySQL DB connection on a MS SQL Server to get my SSIS package which uses this driver to run? Will installing it on my server disrupt anything?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your query is YES and it will not disrupt anything.

Comment: Okay so i definitely need it on the target server. I was hoping that it was some how encapsulated in the SSIS package....

Comment: No I have checked it. You will not face any disruption!! :)

Comment: I've used the driver for over a year in production without issue.

Comment: How about security risks , when opening a connection to another database outside of your domain?

Comment: @davey: There is nothing specific to this driver or SSIS that should be a security risk. You may want to start a new thread to find out what best practices others use when establishing db connections to servers outside of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar but use the MySQL ODBC driver.  You can also create a linked server and use that, also with the ODBC driver.